# replace line feeds with sed in a certain range of line

Tags: sed

Is it possible to replace /n (e.g., with space) in a certain range of line position with sed?

Here is a sample without range filter. Is it somehow possible to set a range in sed?

```
for f in `find ${_filedir} -type f`
do
  #replace all LF with spaces
  sed 's/\n/ /g' ${f} > ${f}.noCR
done
```

Ok, here a sample:

Let's take some lines:

"I want to break free now"
"And friends will be friends"

I want to replace any "n" with an "m" in range 0 to 16, which results:

"**I wamt to break** free now"
"**Amd friemds will** be friends"

Comment: Have you tried running this code? I don't think it works.

Comment: It's just a snippet to show the context. The sed command works fine, but without range restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited again**

Try `awk`:

```
awk '{l=substr($0,1,10);r=substr($0,11);gsub(/n/,"m",l);print l r}' file
```

where `l` is the left part of the string and `r` is the right and `gsub()` does global substitutions.

**Edited**

I would probably use Bash parameter substitution for that - documentation [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   left=${line:1:16}    # Get left 16 chars
   right=${line:17}     # Get remainder of line
   left=${left//n/m}    # Do global replacement in left part
   echo $left $right    # Show output
done < file
```

**Original answer**

Sure, just on lines 2-8

```
sed '2,8s/foo/bar/' file
```

Or, between start and end patterns:

```
sed '/start/,/end/s/foo/bar/' file
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit unclear: I'din't mean range of lines, but range within a line.
And it's not about \n. It could be any character.

The point is: Is it possible to restrict the range within a line with sed!

Comment: Probably! Please update your question with an example, or two, of what you mean, showing your input and output data.

Comment: My awk solution above is a little more concise.

Comment: With this solution, the show can go on... MUST go on ;-)