# Using sed to make replacements only within part of a line

Tags: sed

**How to replace '.' with '_' within the part of the line before the '=' char in the input below**

Need single sed command to do all three

```
echo "few.num.dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot" | sed 's/\./_/g'
```

required output => few_num_dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot

```
echo "var=nodot" | sed 's/\./_/g'
```

required output => var=nodot

```
echo "var.one=onedot.notthis" | sed 's/\./_/g'
```

required output => var_one=onedot.notthis

Comment: See my awk-based answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810065/replace-line-feeds-with-sed-in-a-certain-range-of-line/22810489#22810489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional branching using the `t` command. It does a loop until the substitution command fails, and the command replaces any `.` character followed by an equal sign:

```
echo "few.num.dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot" | 
  sed ':a; s/\.\([^=]*=\)/_\1/; ta'
```

It yields:

```
few_num_dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot
```

Comment: That'll work so long as the variable's value doesn't contain an `=`.  `sed  ':a;s/^\([^=]*\)\.\([^=]*=\)/\1_\2/;ta'` will be safer.

Answer (score 1):

perl?

```
echo "few.num.dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot" | 
perl -pe 's/^[^=]+/ ($x=$&) =~ tr{.}{_}; $x /e'
```

```
few_num_dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot
```

awk?

```
awk -F= -v OFS='=' '{gsub(/\./,"_",$1)} 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way as well,

```
echo "few.num.dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot" |
sed -e '1,/./s/\./_/' -e '1,/./s/\./_/'

few_num_dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot
```

First `-e` replaces the first occurrence of the pattern `.`, next `-e` replaces the next one...

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
$  echo "few.num.dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot"  |awk '/=/{gsub(/\./,"_",$1)}1' FS="=" OFS="="
few_num_dots=/home/user/.hidden/folder.dot

$ echo "var.one=onedot.notthis" |awk '/=/{gsub(/\./,"_",$1)}1' FS="=" OFS="="
var_one=onedot.notthis
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/=/\n&/;h;y/./_/;G;s/\n.*\n.*\n//' file
```

Insert a marker to divide the line, copy the line, translate the characters, append the original line and using the marker reconstitute the line.